# GET request with Postman is not showing JSON outputs

Tags: php, api, http, get, httprequest

I'm working with a PHP REST API, I made this function:

```
 function getNotifications($request) {
     require_once 'db.php';
     $emp = json_decode($request->getBody());
     $id = $request->getAttribute("id");
     $sql = "select * FROM notifications WHERE userid= :userid";

     try {
         $db = getConnection();
         $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
         $stmt->bindParam("userid", $id);
         $stmt->execute();
         $wines = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
         $db = null;

         return json_encode($wines);
     } catch(PDOException $e) {
         echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}';
     }
}
```

When I try to echo the `wines` variable, `echo wines->message;`, it's working, so the problem isn't from the query.
The problem is that when I try to make a call to the API without echo, nothing shows off, not even a message saying that I have no result.

Comment: It's because you're `return`'ing it. You need to `echo` your json response.

Comment: Even the `echo json_encode($wines);` dont work, its only the `$wines->attribute` that works

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you get when you `var_dump( $wines );` before you json encode it?

Comment: `object(stdClass)#101 (6) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["metierid"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["userid"]=>
  string(2) "30"
  ["otheruserid"]=>
  string(2) "40"
  ["message"]=>
  string(50) "Vous avez manqu� un appel de Kebbab Walid (willy)."
  ["readed"]=>
  string(1) "0"
}`

Comment: I've had a similar issue before to do with the encoding and/or special characters in the text. Try this: `echo json_encode( $wines, JSON_HEX_APOS);` and let me know if that produces your JSON. Or potentially try this constant: `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE`

Comment: Tried both, not working :x

Comment: Hrm, okay. run the `json_encode()` and then check either [`json_last_error()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) / [`json_last_error_msg()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error-msg.php) - There might be something in there that tells us what's causing this issue

Comment: Error 5 , msg: Malformed UTF-8 characters, possibly incorrectly encoded

Comment: Oh i guess its because i have an "é" in my `message` database attribute

Comment: Is there anyway that i could get that to work even when having caracters such as "é" ?

Comment: You need to fetch all, you're only fetching one result via `$stmt->fetch`